# regex to replace characters and then remove spaces and hyphens for a url

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to format the names of manufacturers to use in the url.

Example: `IN-X / P.S.M. International`

I wrote a helper method as follows

```
def clean_name(name)
      fn = name.gsub(/[.\/,&()]/, '') #replace these characters with nothing
      fnn=fn.strip.gsub(/[\s]/,'-')   #replace the spaces between the words with hyphens
      fnnn = fnn.gsub(/--/,'-')       #replace double hyphens with single ones
end
```

I know there must be a better way to do this than I have above. Any more experienced programmers have some ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Rails, you can simply do:

```
string.parameterize
```

This comes from [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize). For even more sophisticated slugging, see [ActsAsUrl](https://github.com/rsl/stringex). It can do the following:

```
"rock & roll".to_url => "rock-and-roll"
"$12 worth of Ruby power".to_url => "12-dollars-worth-of-ruby-power"
"10% off if you act now".to_url => "10-percent-off-if-you-act-now"
"kick it en Français".to_url => "kick-it-en-francais"
"rock it Español style".to_url => "rock-it-espanol-style"
"tell your readers 你好".to_url => "tell-your-readers-ni-hao"
```

There are several other options listed in the [Permalinks and Slugs](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs) category in Ruby Toolbox.

Comment: Wow I wish I had asked this earlier. Thanks a lot Mark.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def clean_name(name)
  name.gsub(/[.\/,&()]/, '').gsub(/[\s\-]+/, '-')
end
```